# How to choose the graphic toolkit for PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, gnome, kde-plasma

I'm developing an PyQt application for my clients. The problem is that my default graphical is Gnome and my client KDE. So there is some difference I can not contrôle.

How can I force the pyQt to choose the good graphical system (Gnome) instead of the default system (KDE)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`QApplication::setStyle ( QStyle * style )`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qapplication.html#setStyle) with one of these values as parameter:

- plastique
- cde
- motif
- sgi
- windows
- cleanlooks
- mac

Answer (score 8):

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
```

is the way to go

Comment: Note that you can skip the `QStyleFactory.create` part to `app.setStyle("plastique")`

Comment: Thanks, but when I just the mac style, it does not show the mac widget, does the mac style work only for mac os?

Comment: Haven't tested it Mac OS, but there probably are some elements that can only be displayed on certain OS...