# How to change style in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, styles, qt5

I am writing a Qt5 application by using PyQt.
I would like to understand how to change the style of the entire application.

The old Qt4 calls like:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
```

and the suggested method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200167/how-to-choose-the-graphic-toolkit-for-pyqt) does nothing.

Are they deprecated?
https://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

may be `Cleanlooks` is no longer available on your system. By `QStyleFactory.keys()` you can ask the available styles on your system. On Ubuntu 16.04 and pyqt5 i only get:

```
['Windows', 'GTK+', 'Fusion']
```

edit:

[here you find the qstyleplugin](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/)

containing 6 additional styles, you have to compile it by yourself

2. edit:

on ubuntu 16.04, python3.5 i got it working by installing the styleplugins to QT5 and compile pyqt5 from source against this QT5:

install QT 5.7 by onlineinstaller

in installationdirectory search `qmake`, in my case `/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake`

download qtstyleplugin to an arbitrary directory `git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qtstyleplugins.git` and install it:

```
cd qtstyleplugins
/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake # the qmake from the fresh installation
make
make install
```

now there is a folder „styles“ in `/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/` containing the additional styles.

[download sip-source](http:///opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake), compile and install it

[download pyqt5-source](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), compile and install it, in the step `python3 configure.py` provide the qmake from the QT5-Installation by the `--qmake`-option and look in the output for missing dependencies.

Now the following styles are available:

```
['bb10dark', 'bb10bright', 'cleanlooks', 'cde', 'motif', 'plastique', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

i got an sip-error:

```
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3
```

to prevent it, run `sudo apt-get purge python3-sip` before installing sip [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589497/pyqt5-sip-api-10-level-error-api-11-required#22896854)

Comment: thank you! Very strange, I have also ubuntu 16.04 and Qt5, I get only ['Windows', 'Fusion']. How to add/create more?

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: I get this error 
NameError: name 'QStyleFactory' is not defined

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory`