# Installing PyQt5 from sources: Unable to import PyQt5.sip

Tags: pyqt5, python-sip

I'm trying to build PyQt5 from the sources. I'm running fedora 28 and I installed Qt5 via `dnf`. Installing Sip following [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html) seems OK. But when i try to configure PyQt i got this error:

```
# python3 configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-qt5
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Error: Unable to import PyQt5.sip. Make sure you have configured SIP to
create a private copy of the sip module.
```

According to the [doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/using.html#ref-private-sip) I did:

```
# python3 configure.py --sip-module private.sip
# python3 configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 -n private.sip
```

But i still get the error. So I'm guessing I'm not using it properly. Any suggestions ?

**P.S:** I know (and i did) that it can be done via `pip` but i'm facing the same problem than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201227/how-to-change-style-in-qt5qt/39202315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to install sip-4.19.10 and PyQt5_gpl-5.11.1?

Try a combination of sip-4.19.8 and PyQt5_gpl-5.10.1.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/

Comment: But what if I have sip 4.19.12 and PyQt 5.11.1? Are they incompatible?