# private copy of sip module for pyqt installation

Tags: pyqt5, python-sip

I am facing problem when I try to install PyQt(according to the following link https://www.metachris.com/2016/03/how-to-install-qt56-pyqt5-virtualenv-python3/).

I am able to install everything but got stuck for PyQt installation.For installation it showed me an error that I have to make a private copy of my sip module for the installation . I followed this link([Installing PyQt5 from sources: Unable to import PyQt5.sip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098152/installing-pyqt5-from-sources-unable-to-import-pyqt5-sip)) to make a private copy but got stuck with this error

```
python3 configure.py --sip-module private.sip
python3 configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 -n private.sip
```

It shows an error

```
configure.py: error: no such option: -q
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: To see the correct options, just run `python3 configure.py --help`.

Comment: I run the following command but I do not see any  '-q' command  in any section of help.

Comment: Why would you expect to? You already got an error telling you there's no such option. So use the correct options instead.

Comment: Even if I try to rum the commands available in help section. I get an error like this #Error: Unsupported macro name specified. Use the --show-build-macros flag to
see a list of supported macros.