# QScintilla2 not installed DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qscintilla

I try to run a Python script which is a demo from PyForms, which uses PyQt5, SIP and obviously QScintilla.

```
import pyforms
from pyforms import BaseWidget
from pyforms.controls import ControlText
from pyforms.controls import ControlButton

class Application(BaseWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(Application, self).__init__('Name of the app')

    #Definition of the forms fields
    self._firstname = ControlText('First name', 'Default value')
    self._middlename = ControlText('Middle name')
    self._lastname = ControlText('Lastname name')
    self._fullname = ControlText('Full name')
    self._button = ControlButton('Press this button')
```

I had a lot of trouble to come to this point. One hurdle was to get the suitable PyQt5-Version in combination with SIP. Now Pydev(Eclipse) prompts me the following:

> QScintilla2 not installed
>   DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

(translation DE -> EN: The given procedure couldn't be found)

QScintilla2 is installed and I tried to reinstall in different versions many times. I have no matter how to fix this with PIP.

The current versions under `Windows 8`are:

> Python: 3.7
>   PyForms: 3.0.0
>   AnyQt: 0.0.8
>   PyQt5: 5.10.1
>   PyQt5-sip: 4.19.12
>   QScintilla: 2.10.7
>   sip: 4.19.8

For people who want to know my previous fix for the PyQt5/sip hurdle: [Stackoverflow | Answer from user ntaro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098152/installing-pyqt5-from-sources-unable-to-import-pyqt5-sip)

If you need further information, let me know it, please!

Comment: In SO you should not add to the title SOLVED, what you have to do is post an answer and mark it as correct. ;)

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and installed the latest versions of

> QScintilla
> Pyforms
> SIP
> PyQt5

Order: SIP -> PyQt5 -> QScintilla -> Pyforms

Works now!